# Page for logged in user to Edit/Delete their own content?

Tags: users, content, plugin-gravity-forms, custom-content

Im new to WordPress, I have been working with Drupal for about 6 years and recently switched over to WP, couldnt be happier :)

I have a question that I need some assistance with and was hoping that someone could help me out with. I am using Gravity Forms to allow users to submit content on the Front End, all works great, users are able to come and register then post their own content.

Now, what i need to do is have a page where a logged in user can see a list of all of their posted content and be able to edit/delete the content if they want. Is this possible? Hopefully a Plugin that can help me out or if there is a way to do it myself i am also open to that. Im not great at coding but not a total newbie and can find my way around code if i need to with the help of Google, so if someone could help me out i would really appreciate it.

It would be also good if instead of a page i could display the content on the users profile in a widget or something.

Much appreciated,
Regards

P

Comment: when the user submits a post via GF, is the post not attributed to them?

Comment: Yes it is. They are set as the authors of the posts they submit via GF

Comment: To be clear are you thinking page in admin or front end page? Does your users have access to admin side? Which user role are they assigned?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/

Answer (score 1):

If you are needing users to have the ability to edit/delete their submitted content I would assume they are registered with their own member account on your wordpress website. If this is the case, why not build a custom role for your new members and then restrict everything for that role in the WP-admin to only show the posts add and edit page? This would be more simple in my opinion. Have you tried that?

John